# iOS iPad tableView in single view application

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have universal single view app. In the iphone I created a table view and works just fine but I add a tableview in the iPad nib but the table view never display in my ipad. Any of you can tell me what I'm doing wrong or how can fix this

I really appreciate your help

P.S. Both nibs had been configure to files owner in the same way

Comment: check `@property` and also `@synteshize` ??? is proper ?

Comment: I'm using the same viewcontroller for iPhone y iPad

Comment: probably you are not connect properly its Ipad xib's tableview outlate or its delegate or data-source.

Comment: They are connected exactly the way. Both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it looks like you have linked the table view to the controller, but you have not. You need to check at least three things:

When selecting the table view and checking the connections inspector (the rightmost tab on the right panel) you should see

- `tableView`  under "Referencing Outlets"
- `dataSource` under "Outlets"
- `delegate` under "Outlets"

Finally, ensure that the correct storyboard / xib is used for the iPad.

Comment: as I said in my original question. both nibs are connected to  files owner meaning :tableView under "Referencing Outlets"
dataSource under "Outlets"
delegate under "Outlets"

Comment: Then I guess you have to show your datasource code. Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

first check whether view is getting loaded. if view is loaded then check the frame of tableview. thats the only way. the way you linked the outlets are proper.